# django-simple-history 1.9 break unittests

Tags: django-simple-history

When I run unittests with django-simple-history==1.6.0, it runs fine but with
django-simple-history==1.9.0 it breaks the unittests.
Any ideas how to fix this?

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 90, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 210, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 166, in setup_databases
    **kwargs
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 370, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 376, in create_test_db
    self.connection._test_serialized_contents = self.serialize_db_to_string()
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 413, in serialize_db_to_string
    serializers.serialize("json", get_objects(), indent=None, stream=out)
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 129, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 52, in serialize
    for obj in queryset:
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 409, in get_objects
    for obj in queryset.iterator():
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 238, in iterator
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 829, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 318, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: myapp_historicalbook.history_change_reason
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I had to remove my migration folder in order to be able to run the unit tests.